# list of ints into a list of tuples python

Tags: python, list

`[1, 109, 2, 109, 2, 130, 2, 131, 2, 132, 3, 28, 3, 127]` I have this array and I want to turn it into a list of tuples, each tuple has 2 values in. so this list becomes `[(1, 109), (2, 109), (2, 130), (2, 131), (2, 132), (3, 28), (3, 127)]`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python

Comment: This related issue is about generating a list of **lists**, so it is not an exact duplicate, but it's pretty close, and easy to adapt

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) combined with [slicing](http://techearth.net/python/index.php5?title=Python%3aBasics%3aSlices) to create a new [list](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/lists.html) of [tuples](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/tuples.html).

```
my_new_list = zip(my_list[0::2], my_list[1::2])
```

This would generate a new list with the following output

```
[(1, 109), (2, 109), (2, 130), (2, 131), (2, 132), (3, 28), (3, 127)]
```

The process behind this is quite simple. We first split the existing list into two new lists using [slicing](http://techearth.net/python/index.php5?title=Python%3aBasics%3aSlices).

```
print my_list[0::2] # [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]
print my_list[1::2] # [109, 109, 130, 131, 132, 28, 127]
```

Then use [zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to combine these two lists into one list of tuples.

```
print zip(my_list[0::2], my_list[1::2])
```

Answer (score 9):

```
>>> it = iter(L)
>>> zip(*[it]*2)
[(1, 109), (2, 109), (2, 130), (2, 131), (2, 132), (3, 28), (3, 127)]
```

---

#### Explanation

`it = iter(L)` creates iterator on the initial list

`[it]*2` crates the list consisting of the same iterator twice.

`*` used at the first place in the parameter is used to unpack the parameters, so that `zip(*[it]*2)` turns into `zip(it,it)`. Though you can use `zip(it,it)`, `zip(*[it]*2)` is a more general construction, which can be extended to any number of values in the resultant tuple.

The core of this approach is that `zip` on each iteration tries to get one value from each argument. But it turns out that all the arguments are effectively the same iterator, so it yields every time a new value.

Comment: Super-clever!! +1 for that. But the one trying to understand code including these lines is worse off.

Comment: @NiklasR Yeah, I have been writing explanation after typing the core of the answer.

Comment: It looks very nice, but unfortunately it relies on the fact that `zip` takes values from the iterators left to right, which may be logical considering its output, but is actually an implementation detail.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

```
lst = [1, 109, 2, 109, 2, 130, 2, 131, 2, 132, 3, 28, 3, 127]

print [(lst[i], lst[i + 1]) for i in xrange(0, len(lst), 2)]
#[(1, 109), (2, 109), (2, 130), (2, 131), (2, 132), (3, 28), (3, 127)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by ovgolovin's answer:

```
>>> it=iter(L)
>>> [(el, next(it)) for el in it]
[(1, 109), (2, 109), (2, 130), (2, 131), (2, 132), (3, 28), (3, 127)]
```

May be a little easier to see how it works.  Can also reverse the tuple order:

```
>>> it=iter(L)
>>> [(next(it), el) for el in it]
[(109, 1), (109, 2), (130, 2), (131, 2), (132, 2), (28, 3), (127, 3)]
```